# Multi user login to same session

Tags: login, session, multi-user

I need to have a machine that anyone can log into but everyone has the same desktop, open windows, session etc. Essentially individual login that could somehow map to a common user.

We want to pair program and if Person A logs in in the morning Person B doesn't want to wait for the Person A to come back from lunch to continue work.

Is this possible? Or do you know of any workarounds or tools I could look into?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there may be a bit more to what you want to achieve, besides sharing the environment as you describe, but I'll go with what you've posted

If pair programming isn't a prerequisite, you can just run a virtual machine, like VirtualBox. It can be placed in a shared location accessible to other users. Whoever wants to carry on can fire up the virtual machine and carry on from whatever state it was left in.

Otherwise, have a look at the following official documentation on desktop sharing:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-desktop.html